# Selecting multiple cells at a same time having same cell value

Tags: excel, vba

in a worksheet I want to select the inputbox's input i.e. suppose "A" which is incurred in multiple cells in multiple location. I want to select all the cells referring to letter "A" at the same time.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectBattleship()
    Dim BattleShip As Range
    Dim Name As String
    Dim store As Variant
    Dim cell As Range

    Set BattleShip = Range("A1:J10")

    Name = InputBox("Value?")

    For Each cell In BattleShip
        If cell = Name Then
            store = cell.AddressLocal & cell.AddressLocal

        End If


    Next cell
    store.Select

End Sub
```

I expect all the cells containing the letter "A" will be selected together.

Comment: Selecting in itself is rarely of use - what do you actually want to do with these cells? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build a `Union()` and use it:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SelectBattleship()
    Dim BattleShip As Range
    Dim Name As String
    Dim store As Variant
    Dim cell As Range, rSelect As Range

    Set BattleShip = Range("A1:J10")

    Name = InputBox("Value?")

    For Each cell In BattleShip
        If cell.Value = Name Then
            If rSelect Is Nothing Then
                Set rSelect = cell
            Else
                Set rSelect = Union(rSelect, cell)
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
    If rSelect Is Nothing Then

    Else
        rSelect.Select
    End If

End Sub
```